# Do own brand organic searches improve your overall SEO?

Tags: seo, links

I noticed something interesting at https://www.wisepricer.com/partner.php 
Every outgoing link is actually a Google Search, rather than a link to the partner's domain.

So it got me wondering, can this behavior make the Google Algorithm give greater SEO juice than a direct link?

And in general, if your domain is searched a greater number of times, does your overall SEO improve overall?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think those partners are gaining anything by the main website linking to Google search results. They would probably gain more link juice if it were a direct link. The image tags of the partner logos do not contain `alt` attributes. So I highly doubt that page was created to help boost their rankingss.

Linking to search results I don't think does anything to help you. How would Google or any other search engine know which result you intended to pass link juice to?

What I have seen is with enough searches for a brand or company name plus a keyword or phrase which they want to be found for that search can appear as a related search. An example is los angeles xyz services. A local specific search with no company name. Now because many searches were done for Company A los angeles xyz services. Google may show it as a suggested similar search which may help get you traffic if the person runs that search and goes to your website. This is all theory though without having tested.